# Obtaining Car Rental Make and Model from Car Availability REST APIs

Tags: sabre

The car availability REST API returns car types and their associated fares, but I can't find a way to determine each potential car rental's make and model.  Does anyone know a way to do this which doesn't involve using any SOAP APIs?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually no, the only service, at the moment, that could be used to return makes' information would be **[Car Location Details](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/ground_transportation/search/Car_Location_Details)**

This is a basic example of how I believe the request should be done:

```
<OTA_VehLocDetailRQ ReturnHostCommand="true" Version="2.2.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
    <VehAvailRQCore>
        <VehRentalCore>
            <PickUpLocation LocationCode="MIA"/>
        </VehRentalCore>
        <VendorPrefs>
            <CarExtras Code="MAKES"/>
            <VendorPref Code="ZE"/>
        </VendorPrefs>
    </VehAvailRQCore>
</OTA_VehLocDetailRQ>
```